# How to select by third table Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have `Posts` table.

Each `Post` have categories:

```
Post_categories
 _________________
id post_id | category_id
```

Also there is table:

```
User_categories
__________________
category_id | user_id
```

So, I need to select all rows from `Post` table, where `User_categories.user_id =9` and `User_categories.category_id = Post_categories`.

So, others words, I need to show articles on that categories user subscribed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving this another try with the Eloquent way.

In the Post model class, define the many-to-many relationship with Category model. (The pivot table is *Post_categories*)

```
class Post {
public function categories()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'Post_categories', 'post_id', 'category_id');
}
}
```

In the User model class, define the many-to-many relationship with Category model. (The pivot table is *User_categories*) Also in this class, define the posts() function as a query on the relationship existence.

```
class User {
public function categories()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'User_categories', 'user_id', 'category_id');
}

public function posts()
{
return App\Post::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use($this) {
$query->whereIn('posts.cat_id', array_column($this->categories->toArray(), 'categories.id'));
});
}

}
```

To get the posts that a user subscribes to

```
App\User::find(9)->posts;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you go to chat?

Comment: Sure. Buzz me when u r around.

Comment: I am here, lets go

Comment: how to move in chat?

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think there's a private chat feature in Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

I suggest starting with reading the documentation here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent

and here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

especially this part: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

First you will want to define the models for `Post`, `Category`, and `User`.

After that make sure that you have the right relationships defined according to your needs, but as I understand from your question you want many-to-many relationships.
For this kind of relationship you will need to create pivot tables as well. As a convention you will name them `category_post`, `category_user` (lowercase name of the two models from the pivot table, in alphabetical order)

Your pivot tables migration should look something like, for example for `category_post`:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('category_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['skill_id', 'user_id']);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

After setting up the tables you will have to make sure that the relationships are correctly defined.

After that you should be able to do something like:

`User::find(9)->posts;`

Comment: Unfortunately,, but you dont got my issue right, look please this SQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec162/3/0

Comment: Well, the answer still stands, you just have to adapt it for `Announcement` instead of `Post`

Comment: Can we go to chat?